# Highcharts Gantt change first day of the week

Tags: highcharts, x-axis, highcharts-gantt

I use Highcharts Gantt charts and I need to change the first day of the week displayed on the X-Axis.
By default, the week starts on Monday but I need the week to start on Wednesday (until next Tuesday).
How can I achieve that ?
On the following example https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/xqp6whyj/ I tried to change the
`startOfWeek: 3`
but with no incidence.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `startOfWeek`, but for the second x-axis. For example:

```
  xAxis: [{
    currentDateIndicator: true,
    min: today - 3 * day,
    max: today + 18 * day
  }, {
    startOfWeek: 3
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0t1v4gLb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.startOfWeek